# netbeans web.xml file is same as pom.xml file in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, model-view-controller, netbeans

Am a beginner with netbeans IDE. I want to know that web.xml file in Netbeans hierarchy is same as that of pom.xml file in Eclipse IDE.

Where as in Eclipse, when we create a project it comes with pom.xml file. We can modify when we need to modify or to add dependencies. So, how about in Netbeans? web.xml work as similar to pom.xml

Comment: web.xml in netbeans? can you post it? never heard of specific web.xml for NetBeans.

Comment: i found web.xml in code there was no pom file in project hierarchy . I just want to conclude that does web.xml file works similar to pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got this all wrong. Please read through some materials.

***web.xml - deployment descriptor***

Java web applications use a deployment descriptor file to determine how URLs map to servlets, which URLs require authentication, and other information. This file is named `web.xml`, and resides in the app's WAR under the `WEB-INF/` directory. `web.xml` is part of the servlet standard for web applications.

A web application's deployment descriptor describes the classes, resources and configuration of the application and how the web server uses them to serve web requests. When the web server receives a request for the application, it uses the deployment descriptor to map the URL of the request to the code that ought to handle the request.

***pom.xml - project object model***

A Project Object Model or POM is the fundamental unit of work in Maven. It is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project. It contains default values for most projects. Examples for this is the build directory, which is `target`; the source directory, which is `src/main/java`; the test source directory, which is `src/test/java`; and so on.

The POM was renamed from `project.xml` in Maven 1 to `pom.xml` in Maven 2. Instead of having a `maven.xml` file that contains the goals that can be executed, the goals or plugins are now configured in the `pom.xml`. When executing a task or goal, Maven looks for the POM in the current directory. It reads the POM, gets the needed configuration information, then executes the goal.

Some of the configuration that can be specified in the POM are the project dependencies, the plugins or goals that can be executed, the build profiles, and so on. Other information such as the project version, description, developers, mailing lists and such can also be specified.

Go through the below pages.

1. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html
2. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml

Comment: 1.Then which file in net-beans serve like pom in eclipse?  2. If i create maven project in netbeans then it will create POM file?

Comment: even eclipse will have a pom file for maven project. read this article https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html.

Comment: After reading the above mentioned link i came to know that, pom file is independent of platform but dependent on maven project. If i go with Maven project POM file will get generated. Is it rite Gauthaman?

Comment: pom file depends on maven project but not on IDE's.

Comment: Thank you Gautham Sahadevan